# Prove or dis-prove that it always holds or not $\lambda(G) \leq \chi(G) $

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I want to prove that this inequality holds or not?
 The inequality is $\lambda(G) \leq \chi(G) $
where $\lambda(G)$ is the  minimum number of edges  whose deletion from a graph $G$ disconnects $G$, also called the line connectivity and $\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number of graph.

I would be greatly thankful if somebody will tell the answer that how to prove or disprove this inequality?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Why don't you explain what $\lambda$ and $\chi$ are, and for that matter what $G$ is?  Not everyone is using the same textbook as you.

Comment: @ Erick Wong, I am so sorry for my mistake.Can you please tell me answer if it holds then why it holds this inequality?

Comment: The idea is to disprove this inequality by finding a graph where the chromatic number $\chi(G)$ is smaller than the "line connectivity" (also called [edge connectivity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EdgeConnectivity.html)) $\lambda(G)$.

Comment: There are many families of graphs with small chromatic number and large edge-connectivity. For example, the hypercube $Q_n$ is bipartite (and hence has chromatic number $2$) and its edge-connectivity is equal to $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to disaprove the inequality. For a complete bipartite graph $K_{3,4}$, $\lambda (K_{3,4})=3$ and $\chi (K_{3,4})=2$.

Answer (score 3):

If $\lambda$ denotes the edge connectivity, then what is 
$$\lambda(K_{m,n}) , \chi(K_{m,n})?$$

Comment: @ N.s i couldn't understand what the argument here to prove or disprove it.Can you please explain it?

Comment: @MaazAmjad What is the Chromatic Number of the complete bipartite graph? What is the edge connectivity? You should know these...

Comment: @ N.s , Thanks for your guidelines, suppose graphs is non bipartite then inequality will hold again? This is confusing point that for simple graphs, this inequality will work or no?

Comment: @MaazAmjad The inequality is far from holding for large Bipartite graphs. Pick such a graph and add an edge, it still fails but the graph is not bipartite...

Comment: @MaazAmjad Also, you seem not to know this basic logic fact: How do you disprove that something always holds?

Comment: @ N.s , Thank you so much for your help.Actually I am not familiar about more Graph theory and trying to learn it.Thanks a lot again.